# Node-browserify isn't producing any output

Tags: node.js, browserify

I installed node-browserify globally using `npm install browserify -g`, but the module isn't working as I expected. After installation, I tried running the command `browserify entry.js -o entryBrowserfied.js` in the same folder as  `entry.js`, but the command doesn't generate a JavaScript file in the same directory as entry.js, and doesn't produce any console output either. How can I generate "browserified" modules from commonJS modules, now that this command doesn't seem to be working?

The full console output (with the commands that I've entered) is shown below:

```
anderson@anderson-Ideapad-Z560 ~/Dropbox/JavaScript projects/fractal-replacement-images/requireJS_modules $ browserify entry.js -o entryBrowserfied.js
anderson@anderson-Ideapad-Z560 ~/Dropbox/JavaScript projects/fractal-replacement-images/requireJS_modules $
```

I'm still not sure why this command isn't generating a file from entry.js as described in the documentation.

Comment: Here is the documentation that I'm following: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

Comment: 1) What version of node are you running, 2) Try running it without the `-o` option which will print to stdout (just to see if it is compiling)

Comment: Running the command `browserify entry.js entryBrowserfied.js` doesn't produce any console output at all. I'm using version 0.8.17 of nodejs.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that `entry.js` is not in the directory you are in when you run the command, or that it is inaccessible. Also I meant run `browserify entry.js` so that it spits out the complied JS to stdout

Comment: @Chad It turns out that the path variable was not correctly named - in some Linux repositories, the `node` package is called `nodejs` instead. I re-installed the latest version of node.js from source, and everything is working fine now.

Comment: I recommend you use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) it will help a lot.